# List duplicate files inside a folder in C#: Leveraging LINQ.AsParallel

Tags: c#

I have written following algorithm into C# code to list down the files inside a folder recursively.

1. Begin Iterating through the list of files in the directory & its sub
   directories.
2. Store file Name & Path in a list.
3. If current file matches any other file in the list, during
   mark both files as duplicate.
4. Fetch all files from the list which were marked duplicate.
5. Group them by name & return.

The implementation is very slow on a folder containing 50,000 files and 12,000 sub directories. As disk read operation is basically time consuming task. Even **LINQ.Parallel()** doesn't help much.

**Implmentation:**

> ```
> class FileTuple
> {
>     public string FileName { set; get; }
>     public string ContainingFolder { set; get; }
>     public bool HasDuplicate { set; get; }
>     public override bool Equals(object obj)
>     {
>         if (this.FileName == (obj as FileTuple).FileName)
>             return true;
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

1. FileTuple class keeps track of filenames & containing directory, the
   flag keeps track of duplicate status.
2. I have overridden the equals method to compare only files names, in
   the collection of fileTuples.

Following method finds the duplicate files and return as a list.

```
    private List<FileTuple> FindDuplicates()
    {
        List<FileTuple> fileTuples = new List<FileTuple>();
        //Read all files from the given path
        List<string> enumeratedFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(str => str.Contains(".exe") || str.Contains(".zip")).AsParallel().ToList();
        foreach (string filePath in enumeratedFiles)
        {
            var name = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
            var currentFile = new FileTuple { FileName = name, ContainingFolder = folder, HasDuplicate = false, };

            int foundIndex = fileTuples.IndexOf(currentFile);
            //mark both files as duplicate, if found in list
            //assuming only two duplicate file
            if (foundIndex != -1)
            {
                currentFile.HasDuplicate = true;                    
                fileTuples[foundIndex].HasDuplicate = true;
            }
            //keep of track of the file navigated
            fileTuples.Add(currentFile);
        }

        List<FileTuple> duplicateFiles = fileTuples.Where(fileTuple => fileTuple.HasDuplicate).Select(fileTuple => fileTuple).OrderBy(fileTuple => fileTuple.FileName).AsParallel().ToList();
        return duplicateFiles;
    }
```

Can you please suggest a way to improve the performance.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For one, your code cannot produce any matches because `str.Contains("*.exe")` is false for all file names because of the star.

Comment: Second, you are in an imperative mindset. You are adding things to a list and such. State mutation is not good, neither in sequential nor in concurrent code. Instead, you should be grouping on the file name and looking for groups where `Count() > 1`.

Comment: Typo, have rectified, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `.Contains(".exe")`? C'mon, shouldn't you use `.EndsWith(".exe")`?

Comment: @Theraot Or maybe even `Path.GetExtension(filePath)=".exe"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you please suggest a way to improve the performance.

Well one obvious improvement would be to use a `Dictionary<FileTuple, FileTuple>` as well as a `List<FileTuple>`. That way you wouldn't have an O(N) `IndexOf` operation on each check. Note that you'll also need to override `GetHashCode()` - you should already have a warning about this.

I doubt that it'll make very much difference though - I'd expect this to be mostly IO-bound.

Additionally, I doubt that the filtering and ordering at the end is going to be a significant bottleneck, so using the `AsParallel` in the final step isn't likely to do much. Of course, you should *measure* all of this.

Finally, the whole method can be made rather simpler, without even needing the `HasDuplicate` flag or any overriding of `Equals` / `GetHashCode`:

```
private List<FileTuple> FindDuplicates()
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*.*", 
                                    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(str => str.Contains(".exe") || 
                           str.Contains(".zip")
                    .Select(str => new FileTuple { 
                               FileName = Path.GetFileName(str),
                               ContainingFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(str))
                            })
                    .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.FileName)
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) // Only keep duplicates
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)       // Order by filename
                    .SelectMany(g => g)        // Flatten groups
                    .ToList();                     
}
```

Comment: Linq looks easy, you just use one of each :) Just a joke, it looks so advanced :)

Comment: @radbyx: Ignore the overall "grandness" of it - follow each step in turn. The beauty of LINQ is the composition - that you can build a complicated query out of simple steps.

Comment: Yes taking each step at the time and understand them and knowing what they return must be key, like you said :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon, lets say to add another filter criteria fileSize, I would be adding a new property FileSize in the tuple. In this case, Do I have to repeat                  .GroupBy(fileTuple => fileTuple.FileSize)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(g=>g)  after flattening groups ?

Comment: @autrevo: Is that meant to be part of the grouping? If so, then no - you'd use `.GroupBy(tuple => new { tuple.FileName, tuple.FileSize })` and then `.OrderBy(g => g.Key.FileName)` for the ordering. Basically your requirements aren't entirely clear from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is critical I can suggesting using a third party library from http://www.voidtools.com/download.php , try downloading this tool and run a few queries, it will be lighting fast, it works by building an index of files and directories over entire file system on first run , the index constructed very fast in under a minute and takes some time both on memory and disk but after that queries will be blazing fast you can look in their C# example how to use it in your code.

Comment: Hi Michael, The code looks promising. Have you been able to step into the code of Everything.c. I think wrapping the code into C++/CLI project and then directly referencing the generated DLL would be better. What do you say?

Comment: I did not tried to compile everything.c , I think it possible to do  as you like , but I personally would feel safer with existing dll.